# Using angular I want an event to fire after multiple selections are made in a drop down

Tags: angularjs

```
<select multiple = "multiple" size="2" data-ng-model= "selected" data-ng- options="p for p in data.Ps" data-ng-change ="DoStuff()"></select>

DoStuff()
{
//stuff
}
```

I want DoStuff to execute after the user uses shift to select multiple options.  Right now when I use data-ng-change DoStuff executes every time any option is selected.  I want the user to be able to use shift and select multiple options and DoStuff to execute after they have made all the selections.

Comment: How is angular (or how are you) supposed to know that the user has finished selecting stuff? Just add a button for the user to click when the selection is done.

Comment: You could do `ng-change="DoStuff(selected)"` and in `DoStuff()`, have an array length check: `if(selected.length < 5) return;` if you want it to do nothing unless 5 items are selected.